# .htaccess RewriteRule for category/subcategory/.../ in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I had on `.htaccess` file this code

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-ZA-Z-]+)$ details.php?pro_id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

and when i visit `localhost/index.php` and open any product displayed example `localhost/product-1` that product is displayed. But when i add product in `localhost/country/city/place/product-1` i get page is not found. How to rewrite that `.htaccess` code. On `details.php` page is writen code for displayed product information.

So i have this:

```
localhost/index.php - localhost/product-url
```

And i need this:

```
localhost/index.php - localhost/country/city/place/product-1`.
```

**NOTE:** In some cases i will have 2 categories in some cases 3.

Answer (score 0):

your `.htaccess` should look like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9|]+)/([^/]*)/(.*)$ details.php [B,QSA]
```

this will support all urls

Comment: Now doesn't open product page on old and new `.htaccess`

Comment: When i change my `.htaccess` to this `RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^([0-9A-ZA-Z-]+)/([0-9A-ZA-Z-]+)/([0-9A-ZA-Z-]+)/([0-9A-ZA-Z-]+)$ details.php?pro_id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]` when i try to visit `localhost/country/city/place/product-1` i will automatic redirect to `localhost/index.php`

Comment: what is the content of your `details.php` ?